# Туман войны в RTS на Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Всем здравствуйте!
Необходимо реализовать эффект тумана войны на игровом движке Unity3D. Пробовал создать большую, детализированную текстуру, и уже на ней задавать альфу для отдельных ячеек, но в итоге выходит очень плохое соотношение скорость/качество.

Есть какие-то другие реализации для данной задачи? Туман нужен для основного вида камеры, не для миникарты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут несколько вариантов, зависит от того, сколько DrawCalls вы хотите получить:

1. 1 dc - юзать NGUI для позиционирования затемненных пикселей.
2. 30+ dc - использовать проектор
3. Погуглить, есть куча плагинов.