# Unity-camera/Видимые и не видимые зоны

Tags: unity3d, камера

может кто-нибудь знает как сделать так, чтобы местность открывалась перед игроком? Например как у всяких моба(Dota, HOTS, LOL). Я даже не знаю как назвать это чтобы искать в интернете
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "туман войны" называется, так и гугли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/176689/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-rts-%D0%BD%D0%B0-unity3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти зоны называются: Туман войны